# angulaJS hierarchical select option from object

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularJS, my object is vm.parentList2 (shown below)
Want to show select option in hierarchical format, like below

```
Foundation of Information Technology
Life Skills
    Thinking Skills
    writing Skills
```

I am trying following code,

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="c as c.subject_group_name group by c.categoryType.subject_group_name 
        for c in categories 
        track by c.s_gid" class="form-control" multiple size="10"></select>



vm.parentList2 = [{
    "s_gid": "10",
    "m_s_p_id": "1",
    "subject_group_name": "Foundation of Information Technology",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "sname": ""
}, {
    "s_gid": "11",
    "m_s_p_id": "2",
    "subject_group_name": "Life Skills",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "sname": "",
    "child": [{
        "s_gid": "15",
        "m_s_p_id": "2",
        "subject_group_name": "Thinking Skills",
        "parent_id": "11",
        "sname": "Th.sk"
    }, {
        "s_gid": "15",
        "m_s_p_id": "2",
        "subject_group_name": "writing Skills",
        "parent_id": "11",
        "sname": "Th.sk"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: You might take a look at the sample provided in the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Comment: So such example available in docs

Comment: What about adapting your array structure in order to make the example suitable? The select element for `Color grouped by shade, with some disabled` is not very different from that what you like to get...

Comment: I tried, but its not helping, in my case, hierarchical level can be any depth, for example, head, sub head, sub sub head, sub sub sub head.